# Background Task with Timer in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I have an ASP.NET MVC application hosted on a web server. It is a data visualization program that collects data every 30 seconds using an asynchronous timer method. The application has two different views. However, if the user changes the view or refreshes the page while the `TimerElapsed` method is being called, the web application hangs up. How can I fix this issue?

As alread said I tried to use async function, but it did not work. The `StartReadingCSV()` Method gets called in the `program.cs` file

Here is the CSVReading class with the timer:

```
namespace Powermanager.Models
{
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Powermanager.Data;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Timers;

    public class CSVReading
    {
        private readonly Timer _timer;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

        public CSVReading(ApplicationDbContext context, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            _context = context;
            _env = env;
            _timer = new()
            {
                Interval = 30000 // 30 Seconds
            };

            _timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
        }

        public void StartReadingCSV()
        {

            _timer.Start();

        }

        private async void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            string sourcePath = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "Media", "Test.csv");
            string destinationPath = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "Media", "Copy.csv");


            await ReadCsvAsync(destinationPath, sourcePath);
        }
        private async Task ReadCsvAsync(string destinationPath, string sourcePath)
        {
            File.Copy(sourcePath, destinationPath, true);

            using StreamReader csvReader = new(destinationPath);
            DateTime start = new(2000, 01, 01);

            string inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = await csvReader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
            {
                string[] csvArray = inputLine.Split('$');
                var inputTime = start.AddSeconds(Convert.ToInt64(csvArray[0]));
                var timeIn = await _context.PMDatas.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Time == inputTime);

                if (Int32.TryParse(csvArray[1], out int outputACPower) &&
                    Int64.TryParse(csvArray[2], out long outputLifeEnergy) && timeIn == null)
                {
                    PMData Entry = new()
                    {
                        Time = inputTime,
                        ACPower = outputACPower,
                        LifeEnergy = outputLifeEnergy,
                        Main = csvArray[3],
                        ConnDevices = csvArray[4]
                    };

                    _context.PMDatas.Add(Entry);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would argue that there is not enough info here, but I would highly recommend to renew or at least cleat the db context after each timer callback completion (though doubt that this will help with your issue).

Comment: Can you please post a full [mre] somewhere?

Comment: You mention an ASP.NET MVC application and two different views. Where is this mythical code you speak of? Where are the views? pages? How is the "asynchronous timer method" implemented? I don't see it anywhere in your post.

Comment: Web servers are for running very short transactions to respond to HTTP requests. They are not really meant to run timed events or background processes; in fact their very nature makes this problematic, as you have seen. Why not implement this logic in a separate application, e.g. a Windows Service, or even a simple console app that could run on a scheduler?